# Can't install anything on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

I wanted to install `gparted` on Linux Mint with `sudo apt-get install gparted`. But it didn't work. It had shown me the same message before when I wanted to install other packages. When I try to install something with the software manager, it shows me this: "installing this package could cause irreparable damage to your system".

The message from the terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2)
 libpython3.6 : Depends: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.8-1~18.04.1 is to be installed
 openjdk-11-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.3-2~18.04.1) but 3.7.0-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3.7-minimal : Depends: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.3-2~18.04.1) but 3.7.0-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably install the package using the below:

Make sure the repo sources are up to date

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install the package.

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Once the package determines that you have some missing dependencies, run the following command to fix broken or missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Above command will only download the missing dependencies if you have already installed the package.

Also, if your release is `jessie` (`lsb_release -a`) try installing `jessie-backports` and retry installation.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out, and say if i get any more errors!